# ETL interview questions?

Tags: ssis, etl

In 5 days I'm going to ETL interview. It's my first interview on this subject. What question would I be asked? Most likely they will be about MS SQL Server Integration Service.
If possible, provide the answers.  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think practically. Hand them a printout of a sample file that might need to be imported (possibly simplified to save time). Have them talk about database design, considerations, concerns, possible ways to improve the data. Then bring out a second printout of somehow related and see if they can figure how to validate the one from the other.

Make sure you talk about how much time is available to perform the ETL processes based on business rules and environment.

Require as much pseudo-code as you like, but I personally subscribe to the idea that syntax can be taught cheaply, but learning how to think is a very expensive thing to teach someone; and sometimes it's not even successful.

Also, ask them what standards they would implement if they were to design the optimum layout of the source data. Make sure you consider data distribution beyond your company (if applicable).

Answer (score 1):

> If possible, provide the answers. =)

Keep it high-level if you have to, but don't ask a question that couldn't answer yourself.

I agree with Brad that syntax is not important, it's the thought process.

Another idea is to ask them about how they would pack up and move an office. It gives you insight into the same kinds of decisions needed in ETL (prep, actual moving of stuff, and validation), and you might be more comfortable talking about that than the details of SSIS